# Generating Entities Class from Json in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have an Entity Class which currently has `50` attributes. As requirements change it keep on increasing. I wanted to use the `JSON` file which has all the fields and it will generate these entity classes dynamically whenever I pass that `JSON` File in `C#`. What can I Use to adopt this approach?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give further information about what you have tried so far and about the issue you are struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

If the class is only for storing values then you can just deserialize it into a generic object like so:

```
JObject result = (JObject) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourJsonDataHere);
var katObject = result.Property("kategori").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

use the dot.net power tool extension

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EntityFrameworkTeam.EntityFrameworkPowerToolsBeta4

you can reverse data table and constraints into code first entity code.

Or, you can use powershell and access all the sql server schema information retrieving field name, numeric scale, and chart_octet_length.

```
`
$run_sql="select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
and TABLE_NAME in('your_table')";
class Field{
[string] $Column_Name
[string] $Data_Type
[string] $Character_Octet_length
[int] $Numeric_Scale
}`
```